# how to Extending the WebView correctly?

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I'm using solution of [Scroll webview horizontally inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774642/scroll-webview-horizontally-inside-a-viewpager/9925980)

it's looks very useful, I was reference ExtendedWebView in xml,

```
<ExtendedWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

instance ExtendedWebView in .class,

```
LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layout  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay1, null);
ExtendedWebView webView = (ExtendedWebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

but i got 'Error inflating class ExtendedWebView', so could anybody to help me to give me some ideas, thanks for your time and experience!

heres are entire stack trace,

```
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.vv_package_name.ExtendedWebView
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at com.vv_package_name.vv_main$ExtendedPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(vv_main.java:135)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:801)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:930)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1366)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8226)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8226)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8226)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8226)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8226)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vv_package_name.ExtendedWebView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.vv_package_name-2.apk]
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
12-27 22:14:44.263: E/AndroidRuntime(10824):    ... 33 more
```

if using WebView instead of ExtendedWebView, my code is working fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a full reference to the class, including the package.

For instance,

```
<org.example.myapp.ExtendedWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, but it stills not working, '<com.package_name.ExtendedWebView' and '<com.package_name.class_name.ExtendedWebView' all not working...got error 'Error inflating class com.package_name.(class_name.)ExtendedWebView'

Comment: I think you'll have to paste the entire stack trace and log to get more help.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i'm a noob, it's my problem, i put these extend webview code in main Activity class in one .class file...it should be save with a standalone .class file...:)

```
public class ExtendedWebView extends WebView {
```

Comment: If you did want them in the same class file, you could make it static and reference it in XML via: `<org.example.myapp.MainActivity$ExtendedWebView />`

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me by using this in my XML:

```
 <view
    class="com.example.MainActivity$MyWebView"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```