# Android App Building (Java) - Why is "onWindowVisibilityChanged" in android studio not working?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to keep the WebView media content from stopping when user exits or when screen is locked.

I follow this solutions here but it still stops the media from playing.

[WebView media content stops when the screen is locked ( activity's onStop is called)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812876/webview-media-content-stops-when-the-screen-is-locked-activitys-onstop-is-cal)

[How can I make WebView keep a video or audio playing in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028940/how-can-i-make-webview-keep-a-video-or-audio-playing-in-the-background)

the main bits of my code is something like this:

```
public class WebApp extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    WebSettings webSettings;
    String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Google Pixel 4 Build/QD1A.190821.014.C2; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36";
    public static String url = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getColor(R.color.black));
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nitter);


        
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
        if (visibility != View.GONE) super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    }

}
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            webView.clearHistory();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

would anyone be able to tell me what am I doing wrong even though I think I followed the solution correctly? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

When I researched the same problem, I was able to solve it as follows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055346

On "activity_main.xml" try to:

```
<org.example.myapp.MyWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```