# ViewPager with WebView allowing swiping and disallowing scrolling of WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager, android-webview

I am using `ViewPager` and `WebView`to present `HTML` contents as an eBook. On some pages of the ViewPager I am allowing the `TouchEvent` to be handled by the WebView and on some pages I am letting the ViewPager handle the `TouchEvent` by itself by overriding the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method in the `ViewPager`(some pages are having `TextViews` and `Buttons` without `WebView` 1st and last page here). Here is code for the same-

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (getCurrentItem() == 0 || getCurrentItem() == getAdapter().getCount() - 1)
            return false;
        else {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I am again disallowing the scrolling by setting `OnTouchListener` on the `WebView` using the following code-

```
contentView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                ((BigBeeViewPager) v.getParent().getParent()).onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
            }
            return true;
        });
```

**Problem I am facing is** - When I am trying to swipe the ViewPager from the middle of the pages it doesn't work. I have to start swiping from the end of the pages. However it works fine for the pages which are not having `WebView`
How to allow it to start swiping from the anywhere in the pages.

This behaviour is similar to **Gmail Android App** where `ViewPager` is containing the WebView and Swiping is available from any where. I am not able to figure out how they have done it.

**Note -** When I am intercepting all `TouchEvent` to the `WebView` it disables the long click and text selection too, which is not desirable.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can content displayed inside `WebView` be zoomed and scrolled ? Or  scrolling behavior should be applicable only to the `ViewPager`?

Comment: Scrolling should be enabled with 'ViewPager' only. However zooming and other behaviour like - long click for text selection should be enabled with 'WebView'.

Comment: @Sanjeet Ajnabee Please share the project with demo data. Atleast with viewpager content and webview?

Comment: add proper screenshots so that we can understand your problem easily and help.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go man - an old problem with a nice solution.

Take a look here [Scroll webview horizontally inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774642/scroll-webview-horizontally-inside-a-viewpager)

Comment: Finally worked. Its was damn easy . Thank you so much!

Comment: Please add the answer part from the referred link so other can get answers, Basically the section where allowing /disallowing the scroll to the child views solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

However [MarkySmarky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269429/markysmarky) is extremely helpful to find out the solution but still I will like to write the the answer part so other people can get help.

I solved the problem by overriding the method

```
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y)
```

of `ViewPager` and returning `false` if `v` is the instance of the `WebView`. This is not letting the `WebView` scroll itself and hence `ViewPager` treat it as a nono scrolling child and hence swiping works from the anywhere of the page.

Finally my `ViewPager` is looking like-

```
public class BigBeeViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public BigBeeViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BigBeeViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        return !(v instanceof ObservableWebView) && super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have create a `GestureDetector` and implement that on a `Webview`like this:

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }
    });

          webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                                v.requestFocus();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

And remove the `Interceptor` from `Viewpager` and use the default one without any changes